# Cannot locate python.h on ubuntu

Tags: python, ubuntu

I am trying to install Jupyterlab into my Jetson Nano using `sudo pip3 install jupyter jupyterlab` and got this error.

```
c/_cffi_backend.c:2:10: fatal error: Python.h: No such file or directory
       #include <Python.h>
                ^~~~~~~~~~
      compilation terminated.
      error: command 'aarch64-linux-gnu-gcc' failed with exit status 1
```

I tried `sudo apt-get install python3.6-dev` (and python3-dev and python-dev) but nothing is returned when I enter `locate Python.h` and the previous error still happens.

How do I install Python.h? Thanks in advance.

Comment: can you post the results of `which python` and `which python3` ?

Answer (score 0):

```
sudo apt install python-dev
```

(usually). If you are running something weird like CentOS, check out https://gankrin.org/how-to-fix-fatal-error-python-h-no-such-file-or-directory/

For me, I wasn't installing jupyter, but esptool, so I also had to:

```
sudo apt install libffi-dev
```